# How to clear checkout-data selectedShippingAddress when the checkout page it is refresh by the user

Tags: magento2, checkout, onepage-checkout, shipping-methods, local-storage

I need to get the default shiping method when the user refresh the checkout page.

What I notice is that magento keep the last selected shipping method in the Local Storage:

checkout-data selectedShippingAddress

How can I force back the default shipping method when the page have being refresh.

Comment: As you already knew, magento keeps the selected address in the storage, you just need to clear it.

Comment: Or did you just happen to know it's in the LocalStorage without knowing the actual code that save it there?

Comment: Hi @Jimmy thanks for your comment i am having trouble to clear this storage entry in the quote before the page it is refreshed, I need to put the code in a class that populate a select in the checkout

Answer (score 1):

So the whole fuzz about this localStorage usage is kinda popular for M2 engineers due to the whole "modern technology" approach. For developers on the other hand side its not so ideal.

There are some workarounds to do that, whilst the most easy is probably a new template element that just invalidates and reloads the elements in the localStorage like so:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        require([
            'Magento_Customer/js/customer-data'
        ], function (customerData) {
            customerData.invalidate(['checkout-data']);
            customerData.reload(['checkout-data'], true);
        });
    </script>
```